# How can I get a connection string for a Microsoft Common Data Service Table?

Tags: c#, service, connection-string, powerapps, common-data-service

We'd like to create some C# services to intereact with the Microsoft Common Data services.
We are not using Microsoft Dynamics (we might in the future, but that's maybe and not now), so `https://<organization-name>.crm.dynamics.com` does not seem applicable.

Is there somewhere I should be able to find the Service Uri?
And what do I need to put for most of the other properties?  Which ones are required?

Working the Azure Portal, I can usually click around to find Connection Strings.
Is there someway I can do that within Power Apps?

Answer (score 1):

Actually it IS the same as dynamics, since Dynamics in the cloud is built on the PowerPlatform.

checkout here for connection string info examples:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/data-platform/xrm-tooling/use-connection-strings-xrm-tooling-connect